# Kernel panic after trying to boot back into OS X

Tags: macos, boot, grub, linux-mint

I'm a bit of a newbie here!

I installed Linux Mint today on my MacBook Pro after creating a new partition for it. Unfortunately it didn't recognize my wireless card. After a restart and trying to boot back into OS X in Grub, I got a kernel panic. The situation repeated a few times, so I'm a bit screwed this weekend. As the only source of internet in my apartment is my phone atm, here's a shot of the screen that I see:

[image]

What I want is to possibly somehow disable or bypass Grub and boot into OS X by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert either, but try pressing the `Option` key while booting and see if that works. That should allow you to select the volume to boot from.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533